# Tab link in same tab

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, tabs

I have a tab and it works perfectly but I can not put a link or a button in a dialog this tab, it send me to another window in the same tab (that I am in the first window and click the button I want let me open the second window).
I also read other posts like this in your forum but I could not make it work.

my code:

```
<div id="biztabs">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-1">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">Photo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">Video</a></li>
    </ul>

   <div id="tab-1">
   <p>Nell'anno 1969 è bastata la potenza di calcolo di due Commodore 64 per mandare con successo una navicella sulla Luna; nell'anno 2003 è necessario un Pentium 4 a 2000 Mhz per far funzionare Windows XP. Qualcosa deve essere andato storto.</p>
    <a href="#tab-2">A INTERNAL LINK TO TAB 2</a>
   </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
    <p>Un bambino chiede al padre cosa fossero le icone,il padre risponde: "Sono immagini sacre" E il figlio:"E perchè Windows ne ha tante?" Il padre:"Perchè per farlo funzionare ci vuole un miracolo!!!"</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
    <p>La mia stampante ogni tanto ha la carta esaurita , forse dovrei portarla da uno psicologo ?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( '#biztabs' ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery tabs method `select`

HTML:

```
 <div id="biztabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-1">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">Photo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">Video</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1">
        <p>Nell'anno 1969 è bastata la potenza di calcolo di due Commodore 64 
           per mandare con successo una navicella sulla Luna; nell'anno 2003 è
           necessario un Pentium 4 a 2000 Mhz per far funzionare Windows XP. 
           Qualcosa deve essere andato storto.</p>
        <a id="to-tab-2" href="javascript:void(0)">A INTERNAL LINK TO TAB 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <p>Un bambino chiede al padre cosa fossero le icone,il padre risponde: 
           "Sono immagini sacre" E il figlio:"E perchè Windows ne 
           ha tante?" Il padre:"Perchè per farlo funzionare ci vuole 
           un miracolo!!!"</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <p>La mia stampante ogni tanto ha la carta esaurita , forse dovrei
           portarla da uno psicologo ?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#biztabs").tabs();
    $("#to-tab-2").click(function(){  
         $("#biztabs").tabs("select", 1); // switch to second tab
         return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: This is a better answer than whatever crap I was thinking!  +1

Comment: If you want to add some next/previous buttons to your jQuery UI tabs, check out this CSS-tricks article: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/

It covers dynamically inserting the links in your load so you don't have to specifically name and bind the click event each time